# Different redirection styles with netcat and tee giving different results

Tags: netcat, tee

In trying to trace a simple HTTP GET request and its response with `nc`, I'm running into something strange.

This, for example, works fine: the `in` file ends up containing the HTTP GET request and the `out` file the response.

```
$ mkfifo p
$ (nc -l 4000 < p | tee in | nc web-server 80 | tee out p)&
[1] 8299
$ echo "GET /sample" | nc localhost 4000
This is contents of /sample...
$ cat out
This is contents of /sample...
$
```

However, if I replace the `tee out p` above with `tee out >p`, then the `out` file turns out to be empty.

```
$ (nc -l 4000 < p | tee in | nc web-server 80 | tee out > p)&
[1] 8312
$ echo "GET /sample" | nc localhost 4000
$ cat out
$
```

Why should this be so?

**EDIT:** I'm on RHEL 5.3 (Tikanga).

Comment: (At least FreeBSD's) `tee` doesn't buffer its output.  The shell (i.e. `>`) possibly does, which could explain this, I suppose.

Comment: I'm on RHEL 5.3 (Tikanga).

Comment: @sr_ If you can re-post your above comment as an answer, I could consider making it final... as I think you have given me 'sufficient hope' that I'm not doing anything silly on my end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're using shell redirects to read from and write to the same file. Check `p` afterwards, it will be empty as well.  The shell opens it in read mode, truncating the file, while it's setting up the pipeline before it runs the commands.  However, using `tee`, since it opens the file itself, means that the file isn't truncated until after the contents have been read for the input.  This is a well known and documented behavior and the reason you can't simply use redirects to make inline changes to files.

Comment: *"Check p afterwards, it will be empty as well."* p is a FIFO, so it *will* be empty anyway afterwards.

Comment: Right, didn't see that line. Answer still applies.

Comment: I'm not satisfied with your explanation. There's nothing in `p` to start with, so we can leave the 'truncation' part out. The dataflow starts from the RHS of `nc web-server 80 | `. The web-server response gets fed to `tee`. Now, `tee` by definition would send its output to FILEs **and** to stdout. Now, here, there's just 1 FILEs `out` and the stdout instead of connected to the terminal is redirected to `p`. `tee` would copy the response to both. Only after `p` starts getting written to does the ` < p` start reading data off of `p`. So, would appreciate if you could clarify further.

Answer (score 2):

From FreeBSD's `tee` manpage:

```
DESCRIPTION
 The tee utility copies standard input to standard output, making a copy
 in zero or more files.  The output is unbuffered.
```

*unbuffered*  is the cue, Bash (or your shell's) output redirection (`> p`) is probably buffered, thus causing the different behavior.

(I'm sorry I can't be more certain with this, but I take the +1's on the comment as indicators for this being the right track...)